# How to make the last row close fitting the content?

Tags: excel

I have an excel worksheet ;It has two sheets , one is the main dashboard and the second one is automatically updated According to sheet one ,

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

I want this red text line to closing fit the end of the names
that if I have 9 names it is also being at the end of the names not the end of the paper while printing

[image: third screenshot]

This is the file used above :

https://www.mediafire.com/file/151l7afmmcb6pue/school+file.xlsx/file

Comment: What have you tried so far? Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.